# For a family of short exact sequences of coherent sheaves, can we define the splitting subscheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, short-exact-sequences

This question has been asked in [SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429834/for-a-family-of-short-exact-sequences-of-coherent-sheaves-can-we-define-the-spl).

Let $k$
be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $k$. We can talk about short exact sequences of coherent sheaves on $X$. Let $T$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$. Suppose we have a family of SES's parametrized by $T$, that is a SES of coherent sheaves on $X_T:=X\times_kT$
$$0\to E\to F\to G\to0\qquad (**)$$

such that $E,F,G$ are flat over $T$ via the projection.

For each closed point $t\in T$, denote by $X_t:=X\times_k\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(t))$ and consider the restricted sequence
$$0\to E|_{X_t}\to F|_{X_t}→G|_{X_t}\to0\qquad (*)$$
which is exact by flatness.

My question is about the ''splitting locus''
$$T_{\mathrm{split}}:=\{t\in T:t \textrm{ is a closed point}, \;(∗) \textrm{ splits}\}.$$
Now it is only defined as a subset of closed points.

> I wonder if $T_{\mathrm{split}}$ can be enhanced as a topological subspace or even a subscheme.

For the scheme structure of $T_{\mathrm{split}}$, I 'd like to guess its function of points first. Let $0\to E\to F\to G$ and $X,T$ be as above. Let $\mathrm{Sch}/T$ be the category of schemes of finite type over $T$. I come up two functors
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{split}}:(\mathrm{Sch}/T)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set},\quad T'\mapsto \begin{cases}\{\mathrm{pt}\},&\textrm{the pull back of }(**) \textrm{ on }X_{T'}\textrm{ splits}\\\emptyset,&\textrm{otherwise}&\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{fibre.split}}:(\mathrm{Sch}/T)^{\mathrm{op}}\to \mathrm{Set},\quad T'\mapsto \begin{cases}\{\mathrm{pt}\},&\textrm{the pull back of }(**) \textrm{ on }X_{t'}\textrm{ splits for every closed point }t'\in T'\\\emptyset,&\textrm{otherwise}&\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Obviously $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{split}}\subset\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{fibre.split}}$, and they both detect $T_{\mathrm{split}}$ in the sense that $t\in T_{\mathrm{split}}$ if and only if $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{split}}\big(\mathrm{Spec}(\kappa(t))\big)\ne\emptyset$ (same for $\mathbf{F_{\mathrm{fibre.split}}}$). Natural questions arise:

- Are $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{split}},\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{fibre.split}}$ representable?
- Do $\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{split}},\mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{fibre.split}}$ equal?
- If they are both representable but not the same functor, which one should be prefered?

Comment: A short exact sequence splits if and only if the second morphism has a section. Can you use this characterisation to study $\mathbf{F}_{\text{split}}$?

Comment: If $X = \operatorname{Spec} k$ and $0 \to \mathscr E \to \mathscr F \to \mathscr G \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of vector bundles (locally free sheaves of finite rank) on $T$ that doesn't split, then $T_{\operatorname{split}} = T$ and $\mathbf F_{\operatorname{split}}$ is not a Zariski sheaf (the sequence splits on every affine open $U \subseteq T$, but not globally). But representable presheaves are sheaves for the fppf topology, so $\mathbf F_{\operatorname{split}}$ is not representable.

Comment: In this case, $\mathbf F_{\operatorname{fibre,split}} = T$ (i.e. represented by $T$), so this also shows that $\mathbf F_{\operatorname{split}} \neq \mathbf F_{\operatorname{fibre,split}}$. I don't know if $\mathbf F_{\operatorname{fibre,split}}$ is always representable, but my guess would be no.

Comment: Another thing to try is to define the presheaf of splittings $\mathbf{Split}(\mathscr G,\mathscr F) \subseteq \mathbf{Hom}_X(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$, where $\mathbf{Hom}_X(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$ is given by $T' \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal O_{X_{T'}}}(\mathscr G|_{X_{T'}},\mathscr F|_{X_{T'}})$. But the difficulty here is that formation of global hom only commutes with *derived* base change, even in the best possible case \[Tag [08IE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08IE)\]. So $\mathbf{Hom}_X(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$ is not simply $\pi_{1,*}\mathscr Hom(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$.

Comment: (The idea here would be to try to represent $\mathbf{Split}(\mathscr G,\mathscr F)$ by a $T$-scheme first, and then take its scheme-theoretic image in $T$ or something like that.)

Comment: With suitable hyptheses, by cohomology and base change, there is a vector bundle on $T$ whose fibres(!) are $\text{Ext}^1_{X_t}(G|_{X_t}, E|_{X_t})$ and the given extension defines a global section of this vector bundle which vanishes at a point $t$ if and only if (*) split. Anyway, I suggest asking a nearby algebraic geometer to learn more.

Comment: @Johan but don't accidentally ask a vanishing algebraic geometer instead (I always get the two mixed up)...